# Pandas, get elements in an specific order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
col1    col2
Apple     70
Lemon     80
Banana    90
```

and I have a list with the elements of `col1` in a specific order:

```
my_list = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Lemon']
```

I need to get the values of `col2` following the order of `my_list`

```
result = [90, 70, 80]
```

How could I achieve that?
Thanks

PS: I see several solutions to my problem, so maybe I oversimplified it, because some of the solutions will not be efficient for my real problem (my fault for oversimplifying).

The problem is a little more complex, my dataframe has more columns and a lot of rows.

```
col1    col2   col3
Apple     70   red
Lemon     80   red
Banana    90   red
Lemon     2    blue
Apple     3    blue
Banana    4    blue
Lemon     67   green
Banana    68   green
Apple     69   green
```

Basically the values of col1 repeat for each value of col3 (but the order might be different!)

What I need is for each value of col3 to get a vector of values from col2 but always with the same order.

So I obtain my_list by doing:

```
my_list = np.unique(df['col2'])
```

and then I iterate for each element of col3 obtaining the simplyfied example that I posted.

This doesn't change the answers, but I might pick one or another taking in account the whole picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a series and use `map`. This should be more efficient than sorting, using `pd.Categorical`, or list comprehensions.

```
s = df.set_index('col1')['col2']
res = list(map(s.get, my_list))

print(res)

[90, 70, 80]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) if `unique` values of `col1`:

```
a = df.set_index('col1').reindex(my_list)['col2'].values.tolist()
print (a)
[90, 70, 80]
```

Or [ordered categoricals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=my_list, ordered=True)

df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(cat_type)

df = df.sort_values('col2', ascending=False)
print (df['col2'].tolist())
[90, 80, 70]
```

---

```
df['col1'] = pd.Categorical(df['col1'], my_list, ordered=True)

df = df.sort_values('col2', ascending=False)
print (df['col2'].tolist())
[90, 80, 70]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas 0.15 introduced [Categorical Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)

```
df = ...
my_list = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Lemon']

df['col1'] = pd.Categorical(df['col1'], my_list )
df.sort("col1")

result = df['col2']
```

Answer (score -1):

`pandas` has "Built-in" sorting methods, try this:

```
df['column'].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Comment: I don't need them to be alphabetically sorted. This doesn't solve my question.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, why do you think, they will be alphabetically sorted?

Comment: I don't see how this code uses `my_list` to sort the values.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, got it. seems i jumped the gun